# How do I make the indoor svg drawing for OSM Buildings?

Tags: openstreetmap, indoor

How do I make the indoor svg drawing?

I could not find the source.

Can you tell me how to do?

http://osmbuildings.org/examples/indoor/

Comment: svg is http://osmbuildings.org/examples/indoor/indoor.svg and the code generates the WebGL from SVG http://osmbuildings.org/examples/indoor/xyz.js

Answer (score 1):

The source can be found at http://osmbuildings.org/download.php and at the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/kekscom/osmbuildings).

Comment: You got it wrong. svg used in indoor projects. How do I draw SVG?

Comment: How do I convert the geoson and osm xml file to svg?

Comment: I have problems understanding your comments. The project you mentioned uses WebGL, not SVG. And you asked for the source for which I listed the corresponding links.

If you want to create a SVG map then take a look at the [SVG page in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SVG) which lists various software. Also see the [SVG-related questions on help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/tags/svg/).